# Vue3: Component isn’t correctly resolved

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3

Goodmorning everyone,
I currently have the following package structure:

- A design system all written in Vue3
- A common package that imports the design system and is shared between all the different apps I have to mantain
- The apps, which import the common library and include the additional features
  Now the problem is that I have a component in the common library that should be imported in the apps, and the structure is like the following:

```
// common component
<template>
  <div class="template">
    <Navigation></Navigation>
  </div>
</template>
```

and, as you can see, the component  is imported from the design system in the following way

```
import { Navigation } from '@personal/design-system';
```

and used in the components section of the file

```
components: { Navigation }
```

However, when I import the common component above in an app, it’s resolved, but the `<Navigation>` component isn’t rendered itself. Here is the unexpected behavior:

```
// WRONG render
<div class="template">
  <navigation></navigation>
</div>
```

so the component isn’t rendered and only the tag is printed in the DOM. In addition to this I have the following warning in console

`[Vue warn]: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().`

Please, could you help me to understand what’s the problem and what’s the correct way to render component like this if we’re working with libraries?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "ere is the unexpected behavior" - how does this snippet differs from the first one? The question contains pieces of code but doesn't give the whole picture where and how you use components. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error could mean that you have multiple copies of Vue. Or it could mean something else. Any way, this is specific to the actual code you have and likely `@personal/design-system`.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, thanks for your response. The two snippets aren't identical. In fact, the first one is the common component, while the second one represents the final results of importing it in a Vue3 app. As you can see the tag '<navigation>' should have been replaced by the actual component, while this isn't happening. Is my information helping you?

Comment: As I said, multiple Vue versions is the first thing to check. This depends on what happens in `@personal/design-system` and the way common component and the app are related. Please, provide MCVE that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think a reproduction is impossible to provide, as the packages are private and my company owns them. Could you please provide me some methods to exclude multiple Vue copies between packages? Thanks a lot

Comment: Check that `@personal/design-system` doesn't have `vue` in nested node_modules. Same for "common" component if it's in separate package. In case nested packages have `vue` dep, make it peer dependency and loose like `*` or `>=3`.

Comment: You don’t need the curly braces when importing the component. Just go ‘import navigation from ‘path’’